# How to add aesthetic text to the background of a forms textbox?

Tags: ms-access

This should be a simple one, using access forms, how can I put background text in a text box, like alt in html, so users are guided like a search box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a text, which appears in empty field and disappears when you move focus to the field, change `Format` property of textbox like this: `@;"Search"`. Text "Search" will be displayed in the empty field.